# How would you get absolute values from a multivariate log-log model?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I have a log-log model that looks something like this:
$$  
\ln (sales) = 8.15 + 0.0516\times \ln(digital) + 0.74\times \ln(tv)
$$
I understand I can interpret the variables in terms of percentage change, however I want to find out the absolute values for each of these terms.
So if sales is equal to 2000, I want to attribute how much of it comes from each of these terms. I'm unsure of how to achieve this since applying exp on the equation makes the equation multiplicative.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "the absolute values for each of these terms"?

Comment: if sales is 2000, and digital is let's say 200 and tv is 500, then I can just plug in those numbers to get the values for digital and tv in log scale. But what I want is to get the values for digital and tv in the normal scale. 
Hope that made it clear.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking how to exponentiate a logarithm?  For how to interpret log regression models, please [see these search results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+regression+interpret).